# Fetching tasks from many queues

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have 2 types of tasks, one that are generated by user and the other one that are created in huge batches. Tasks are going to separate queues ("short" and "long")
When there are tasks in one queue (ie. that huge batch), Celery is fetching only those tasks completely ignoring another queue until the whole batch is done.

```
Example:
send 100 slow tasks to "long" queue
send 100 small tasks to "short" queue
send 100 slow tasks to "long" queue
send 100 small tasks to "short" queue

Celery behaviour:
process 100 tasks form "long" queue
process 100 tasks form "short" queue 
process 100 tasks form "long" queue 
process 100 tasks form "short" queue
```

That is happening even when I set rate_limit for slow tasks, that goes to "long" queue. All I get is slow tasks are blocking system for longer :/
Is there a way to ensure that Celery is fetching tasks from all queues? (I'm using Celery 2.5.1 with RabbitMQ)

Comment: Could that be caused by using default exchange (same for both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch separate celery worker for each queue:

> $ celeryd -Q short
>
> $ celeryd -Q long

In that case each type of task will be processed independently by separate worker.

Comment: This is my solution for the time being. I presented problem in rather generic way. As I have at least 3 queues, and that will only increase with the time. Why after celery can't process task (due to rate limit), stops looking for task that it can process (ie in other queue)?

Comment: Thak you 0x00mh, that looks like only reasonable solution at the moment. I will update the question if I will find better one.